# Where Is DrawingBrush In Windows Metro for XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Im writing a Windows Metro XAML based app in C#, and I want to draw grid lines with a brush on my custom grid control.

In WPF I would create a [DrawingBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingbrush.aspx) to do the job, but there seems to be no equivalent in Metro ???

Does anyone know if this feature exists under another name, or that you achieve the same result differently ?

As an additional note, I do not want to draw lines etc directly on my grid (adding lines to my panel's children collection), It really needs to be done via the background property - i.e a brush.

Thanks

Comment: Looking for the same thing. Kinda discouraging when such basic feature is missing.

Comment: I've filed a Connect bug since this API is key, especially given the need for vectors on modern screens https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/868455/windows-store-xaml-missing-drawingbrush-or-drawingimage

Comment: It's really hard to get Win-RT problems addressed since its not considered .NET and is owned by the Windows team, who don't have a Connect or indeed have any way to engage customers, developer or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinRT-XAML stack is closer to Silverlight - also in its limited graphics features when compared with Silverlight. The only TileBrush for WinRT apps is the ImageBrush, so you would need to save your drawing as an image first. You can't do that with the XAML stack either though - because there is no drawing class and WriteableBitmap has no Render() method. On the other hand - you can access DirectX for any more advanced features and combine some DirectX code with your XAML.

Comment: how am I supposed to export vector graphics into Windows Store apps? There is no way using WinRT XAML?

Comment: There's a [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.path.aspx) element that you can use to show vector graphics. You can open an Adobe Illustrator (.ai) file in Expression Design, then copy&paste into Expression Blend to get your vectors in a XAML app.